# angular js directive for resizing with jquery ui cannot set maximum width

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

here is  the angularJS directive using jquery UI. I want to set maximum width of the element that can be resize within the resize function. How does that possible?

```
 app.directive('resizable', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                callback: '&onResize'
            },
            link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.resizable({ grid:200,  handles: 'e,w'});
                elem.on('resize', function (evt, ui) {


                            scope.$apply(function() {   
                                if (scope.callback) { 
                                    scope.callback({$evt: evt, $ui: ui }); 


                                    //here is where I want to set maximum width


                                } 
                            })



                });


            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-maxWidth) you just have to set the `maxWidth` option :

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
  maxWidth: 300
});
```

You can also call it dynamically :

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "maxWidth" );
```

the fact is if you call it from the resize event handler, I think the change will only affect the next trigger.

Comment: yes we can set maximum width like that. but what i need is i want to set the maximum width dynamically within the resize function.

Comment: ok, so WHY do you want to do that, because it seems a bit hazardous..?

Comment: i want to get the element width from ui object like ui.size.width and according to that value I have to change the maximum resizable width.

Comment: the problem is that the change will affect the next resize event not the current one

Comment: we can set it like this    ui.size.width < maxwidth

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But I think that if you are trying to do such a thing, you are making a (dirty) hack or you misunderstand something.